# Creating a login page with fixed header, footer in Angular2

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I am developing an application using angular2. I am using eclipse Neon to develop this app which uses angular-cli. Now i am trying to create the login page. I have the following code in my app.component.html

```
<nex-header></nex-header>
 <router-outlet style="height:90%;width:100%"></router-outlet>
 <nex-footer style="position : absolute; bottom : 0; height : 28px; margin-top : 28px; background-color: #757575; width:100%;
 padding-left: 100px; color: #ffffff;"></nex-footer>
```

I have a separate header and footer component which i have included in the app.component.html page. i also have a separate component which contains the login contents. I inject the contents of the login page using router-outlet.

Now i want to display a background image  to the contents of the login page alone (not for the header and footer) also i want all the three components to occupy the entire screen. The code i tried wraps the login but i want to make it occupy the entire screen space between header and footer. i am new Angular2 can someone tell what i am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add `background-image: url("your image");` to you style attribute on the router-outlet tag to make the background image specific for that component.